Minimizing Helmholtz free energy in Ising model
Setup
I have a nearest neighbor Ising model:
$$H = - h \sum_i S_i - J \sum_{<ij>} S_i S_j$$
The free energy is:
$$f \sim - \log \sum_{S_1 = \pm 1} \sum_{S_2 = \pm 1} ... \sum_{S_N = \pm 1} e^{- \beta H},$$
so $f$ is a constant.
From the second law of thermodynamics, one can show that equilibrium state of a system is that of minimum Helmholtz free energy (subject to the right conditions -- the system is mechanically isolated, and the system needs to be at constant temperature).
Problem
We cannot minimize the Helmholtz free energy because $f$ is a constant so there is nothing to minimize.
Question
What is correct way to apply the minimization principle (i.e., what should I minimize) in the Ising model to find the correct equilibrium configurations?

The meaning of the minimum property of the thermodynamic potentials has no reference with the fixed external conditions (for the free energy of a magnetic system of the Ising model, temperature, external magnetic field, and number of elementary magnetic moments, the spins). The free energy is minimum as a function of any additional variable describing a possible constrained equilibrium. A natural example, in the case of the Ising model, could be a constraint such that 70% of the spins are equal to $+1$. One could think (and by numerical simulation is quite simple to implement) a sample at equilibrium at fixed $T$, $h$, and $N$, plus such additional condition corresponding to fix the magnetization per site to the arbitrary value of $0.7$. The minimum principle, in such an example, says that the comparison of the constrained system free energy (say $F_{70\%}$, and that of a system without such additional condition (say $F_{unc}$) will show that for all the equilibrium  macrostates the inequality
$$
F_{unc}\leq F_{70\%}
$$
holds,
and the equality is possible only for the macrostates corresponding to an average magnetization per site equal to $0.7$.
Notice that such a procedure is precisely the one applied when one has to decide which crystalline structure is the most stable (i.e., corresponding to the equilibrium without a constraint on the Bravais type or the unit cell) or, in the case of the Statistical Mechanics of magnetic system, the basis for understanding the meaning of the mean-field free energy depending simultaneously on $h$ and average magnetization ($m$), and the rule for finding the equilibrium value of $m$.

This is quite helpful! One part I didn't understand is: "The meaning of the minimum property of the thermodynamic potentials has no reference with the fixed external conditions ..." Does this mean that things like temperature, external magnetic field, and number of elementary magnetic moments do not count as part of the constraints (as opposed to, for example, magnetization per site being 0.7, which is a constraint and thus one can use the Helmholtz minimum principle)?

@PhysicsEnthusiast. Yes, one cannot use a minimum principle on the external conditions. Missing this point would result in nonsense. For example, if one would try to minimize the Helmholtz free energy wrt the external field, the condition of minimum would imply that the only possible equilibrium state is a state with zero magnetization, i.e. zero external field. But we know that equilibrium is possible even at a finite field value. Similarly, minimization wrt temperature would imply that the only possible equilibrium is at the thermodynamic state such that entropy vanishes. I.e., at T=0.
